# Calendar: Show all day event as busy

Tags: mojave

Recently updated to Mojave. When I create an all-day event in Calendar, is there a way to show the whole day as busy?

Comment: I would really love an answer on this question. I've got messed up so many times because of this!

Comment: I switched to Outlook :-/